# Is there anyway to popup a facebox dialog when clicking inside of a table TD cell

Tags: jquery, html-table, facebox

I want to popup a dialog facebox when I click inside a td in an html table.  Is this possible ?

https://github.com/defunkt/facebox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TD as a proxy...

If you have a link in there, you could do something like this:

```
$("td").click(function(){
  $("a[rel='facebox']", this).trigger("click");
});
```

Of course, modifying that code slightly, you could invoke facebox for any link by clicking nearly anything else on the page. Basically, the `td` element serves as a proxy for you. If you click it, it triggers a click on the link that will be capable of opening facebox up.

#### No link? No problem...

If you don't have a link to click, you could create one of the fly, trigger a click, and then remove it.

```
$("td").click(function(e){
  $("<a>") // create our link
    .click(function(e){e.stopPropagation()}) // prevent bubbling
    .attr({ // set its attributes
      'href':'/css/style.css?'+$(this).text(), // append td vals
      'rel':'facebox' // make it facebox-eligible
    })
    .appendTo(this) // append it to the td
    .facebox() // tie it to facebox
    .click() // click it
    .remove(); // remove it
});​
```

So assume we started out with:

```
<td>52</td>
```

We will have an iframe popup pointing to: `/css/style.css?52`.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson - I dont have a link.  i want it to fire anywhere i click inside the cell.   is this possible ?

Comment: How are you going to tell it which element to open?

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson - oh . . i originally didn't understand your answer.  Just for simplicity sake, lets say i have text in that cell with a number and i want it to go to the address http://www.google.com/[myNumber].  where would the link go in your solution

Comment: So you want to load up an iframe with that address, based on a number within the cell?

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson - i want to load up a facebox dialog (i am not sure if you were calling the facebox popup an iframe) with that address. and as per my last comment, i need to have the text in that TD as part of the URL .

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson - ok . .excellent . . just one small issue, the content seems to be appearing twice.   I simplified the code to just show a picture and it also showed the pic twice in the popup

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson - actually let me add one more issue.  in firefox, it always shows the issue twice, in chrome, i dont seem to get any popup and in ie8 it seems to either show the pic once or twice (still can't figure out a pattern)

Comment: @oo: Try my updated code. I've added a call to stop event-bubbling, which should eliminate the double-calls.

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson - hmm   still getting the content twice in Firefox.  i will keep testing

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson - any other ideas ?

Comment: Placing `e.stopPropagation()` on the link within the `td` should stop the propagation back up to the `td` (inadvertently causing another click)